# MongoDB: updateOne если в документе нет нужного поля

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo

Предположим, есть объект какого-то продукта:

```
const prod = {
    _id: 123123123,
    name: "car",
    description: "BMW X6"
}
```

Нужно найти в Mongo документ с таким же _id и посмотреть на поле description. Если там null (или любое falsy значение), то проапдейтить его, взяв description из объекта prod. А если description уже есть, то не апдейтить ничего.

Можно ли как-то это осуществить? Использую Mongoose и метод Model.updateOne

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял, то:

```
Model.updateOne({_id: prod._id, description: null}, {description: prod.description})
```

Сравнение description с null должно работать в случае null или отсутствия проперти вообще. Если нужны другие значение, можно попробовать их объединить при помощи $in:

```
Model.updateOne({_id: prod._id, description: {$in: [null, false, 0, '']}}, {description: prod.description})
```